# Почему такой результат?

Tags: c++, указатели

Пишу универсальный тип данных(мини-версию)
Проблема возникла при вызове `getInside();`

Вывод: `Integer val: -858993460` Почему так? И как исправить?

```
class AnyType
{
  private:
    int *integer;
    double *floating;
    bool *boolean;
  public:
    AnyType()
    {
        integer = nullptr;
        floating = nullptr;
        boolean = nullptr;
    }

    template<typename T>
    AnyType(T val)
    {
        if (typeid(floating) == typeid(T*))
        {
            floating = &val;
        }
    }
    void ToInt()
    {
        int tmp=int(*floating);
        integer = &tmp;
    }
    void getInside()
    {
        cout << "Integer val:" << *integer << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{

    AnyType fff(1.5);
     fff.ToInt();
    fff.getInside();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Не вижу ничего универсального

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка здесь:

```cpp
void ToInt()
{
    int tmp=int(*floating);
    integer = &tmp;
}
```

Переменная `tmp` локальная для метода `ToInt`, поэтому она размещается на стеке. Указатель `integer` указывает на адрес `tmp` внутри стека. Когда выполнение `ToInt` завершается, вы вызываете `getInside`, а он, в свою очередь — методы `cout::operator <<` для вывода строки и числа.

Эти методы размещают в стеке свои переменные, перезатирая значение `tmp`, которое вы там разместили.

Для решения вашей задачи в C и C++ используют конструктор типа [`union`](http://www.c-cpp.ru/books/obedineniya), *объединение*.

Альтернативное решение, которое подходят для объектно-ориентированного языка — абстрактный базовый класс `Variable` и наследники типов `IntVariable`, `DoubleVariable`, и так далее.

Решение с указателями сложное для такой задачи.

Answer (score 3):

В переменной `floating` будет содержаться указатель на локальные переменные `val` `tmp` которые выходят из области видимости делая указатель невалидным. Соответственно необходимо присваивать указателю адрес переменной, выделенной в куче или каком-нибудь внутреннем буфере.

Comment: @VTT.Tоесть, мне надо скопировать значение `val`,в конструкторе в буферную переменную тогоже типа, а потом передать ссылку на буфер в `floating`?

Comment: Я сделал так. Перед проверкой типа : `T atas= val;` и в проверке типа `floating = &atas;` Но не помогло.

Comment: @AwesomeMan Если написать `T atas= val;` перед проверкой типа, или в проверке типа, или где угодно внутри метода и потом сделать `floating = &atas;`, то указатель будет по-прежнему указывать на локальную переменную, которая сразу же выходит из области видимости.

Comment: спасибо, я просто не сразу понял твой ответ.